# State change in one component in a separate reducer affecting the state on another reducer?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

So, I have a component with Device Settings. The user can update these settings, all is well until now.

I also have another component with some other settings called Inputs, the data for it is just an array of settings pretty much. I also have a resolver that sits on the navigation to this component, so it has to take one but there is a filter to the resolver that makes sure that the array isn't empty.

This works perfectly fine until there is a change in the device settings. When there is a change, the array that comes from a selector in the Inputs component's reducer, becomes empty for a couple of seconds, and then fills up with the normal values again(I am displaying this by logging to console a selector that selects all the elements from that state). This presents a problem because I can either bypass the filter, which puts me to the page when it's empty and it looks broken until values are filled, or my navigation gets stuck in the resolver because the Observable doesn't get a nonempty array sometimes.

I can't post entire code but I can provide snippets of required stuff if you let me know what you wanna see

Reducer 1:

```
export interface DeviceSettingsState {
  device: DeviceSettings;
  systemTime: SystemDateTime;
}
...
export const initialDeviceState: DeviceSettings = undefined;
export const initialSystemTimeState: SystemDateTime = undefined;

// Update success is the problem
export function deviceReducer(
  state: DeviceSettings = initialDeviceState,
  action: DeviceSettingsActionUnion
): DeviceSettings {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DeviceSettingsActionTypes.LoadSuccess:
      return <DeviceSettings>action.payload;
    case DeviceSettingsActionTypes.UpdateSuccess:
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Reducer 2:

```
// Internal Object is just an object with a bunch of fields. The state in this case is a list of those objects
export interface InternalObjectEntityState extends EntityState<InternalObject> {
  mode: number;
}

const adapter: EntityAdapter<InternalObject> = createEntityAdapter<InternalObject>({
  selectId: selectUniqueInternalObject,
  sortComparer: sortByInstanceAndObjectType
});

const initialSate: InternalObjectEntityState = adapter.getInitialState({
  mode: 0
});

export function internalObjectsReducer(
  state: InternalObjectEntityState = initialSate,
  action: InternalObjectsActionUnion
): InternalObjectEntityState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case InternalObjectsActionTypes.LoadSuccess:
      return adapter.addAll(action.payload, state);
    // 25 Mar 2020 Onur, Handling the UpdateMode action type
    case InternalObjectsActionTypes.UpdateMode:
      // 08 Apr 2020 Onur, proper way to update state
      return { ...state, mode: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// And below is the selector that yields empty state when an update on the other reducer happens
export const selectInternalObjectEntityState = (state: AppState) => state.internalObjectState;

export const {
  selectIds: selectObjIds,
  selectEntities: selectObjEntities,
  selectAll: selectAllObjs
} = adapter.getSelectors(selectInternalObjectEntityState);

export const selectCurrentMode = createSelector(
  selectInternalObjectEntityState,
  (state: InternalObjectEntityState) => state.mode
);

// This one
export const selectAnalogAndBinaryInputsForMode = createSelector(
  selectAllObjs,
  selectCurrentMode,
  (state: InternalObject[], mode: number) => {
    // Console loggging state here gives an array of items mostly, when there is a change on the other reducer, it becomes empty for a bit
    return state.filter(
      obj =>
        (obj.objectType === BACnetObjectType.analogInput ||
          obj.objectType === BACnetObjectType.binaryInput) &&
        getIndex(obj, mode)
    );
  }
);
...
```

I'm guessing it happens maybe because of the use of an adapter in one reducer but not the other, but I couldn't find the issue. There is a visual update we're planning on both of these pages anyway so if I can't figure it out by then, I will just rewrite it all, but I'm actually curious what could be causing this.

Fyi, most of that is not my code, it's code that was there when I joined the company.

Connecting reducer 1 to module:

```
...
imports: [
    SharedModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('device', deviceReducerMap),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([DeviceSettingsEffects])
  ],
...
```

Connecting reducer 2

app/store/reducers/index.ts:

```
...
// The interface of the AppState
export interface AppState {
  internalObjectState: InternalObjectEntityState;
}

// A map of all the reducers
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  internalObjectState: internalObjectsReducer
};
```

app.module.ts:

```
...
StoreModule.forRoot<AppState>(reducers, {
      metaReducers,
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: true,
        strictActionImmutability: true,
        strictStateSerializability: true,
        strictActionSerializability: true
      }
    }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot(appEffects),
...
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it is hard to understand exactly the case and a code snippet would be great.

Instead of handling the same action in different reducers you could use ngrx/effects with an effect that creates 2 actions, one for each reducer to keep their contexts unmixed.

If you want to skip unacceptable values (those 2 seconds), you could add `filter` operator right after `select`, something like `filter(v => !!v)` for falsy values and `filter(v => v.length > 0)` for empty arrays.

Comment: Yeah fair enough, which part of the code do you want to see? It's a work thing so I can't really post the entire thing.  
It's not really handling the same action in 2 reducers, it's more like 2 separate reducers doing separate things completely, but for some reason when one has a state change, the other's state goes empty array for a couple seconds.  
And exactly, I already have that in the code which made my navigation hand, I just removed that to work around that problem. For some reason, sometimes, not every time, the array just gets stuck empty when I have that filter.

Comment: so, do you mean you have 2 reducers, and when the first one updates its state the 2nd one gets an empty array during its state update, is it correct? Then please post code of the handlers of the actions in the reducers.

Comment: Yes exactly, during and/or right after. If I have that empty checking filter, sometimes it just gets stuck empty. If I don't, it becomes empty for a second or two, then repopulates.  I will add the code tomorrow morning

Comment: good, drop a message here and I'll take a look. Sounds like a bit mess in dispatches and effects.

Comment: An update that I've realized while researching more about this issue: The state that the first reducer deals with is in a feature store, while the second one is in a root store. There is also another feature store that is again unrelated to the other 2 stores, but changing the state of that didn't seem to affect the root store like the other feature store does. My next step will be to go through both feature stores and see what was done differently that might affect anything

Comment: Looks fair, might you share how you connect reducers to the feature module?

Comment: Thanks, I assume `deviceReducerMap` contains `deviceReducer `, but how is `internalObjectsReducer` connected in its module?

Comment: It does, yes, and editing post again with further code

Comment: Sorry mate, the code you have above is fine. it doesn't cause lags. I would check effects. Simply disable them and then enable one by one checking if it affects the behavior.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find anything either, that's why I'm really stuck at this right now but that's a good suggestion, I'll try that out.

Comment: in the app module where you have root store module subscribe to the StoreActions and try to debug them, maybe their sequence can bring light.